# How to stop unwanted scroll in collection view after invalidating layout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

i am working on collection view with dynamic cell height. What happens when i invalidate the layout the some cell grows or shrinks in height that result unwanted offset for collection view.

Currently i am saving the visible top index path before invalidating the layout and scrolling the collection view to that index path after invalidating the layout but this this results in weird clear screen flash.

How can i overcome this problem?